# Redundant Oauth authentication server (high availability / failover)

Tags: spring-oauth2

We are considering to use oauth authentication between our microservices.
It's very important these services will keep working even when the authentication server is down.

Shouldn't the AuthorizationServer be redundant in my scenario ?

We are using our own AuthorizationServer (based on https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/authserver.git)
(and are using latest stable spring cloud / spring boot apis)

I couldn't find any documentation about working with a second AuthorizationServer so microservices keep working when first AuthorizationServer is down. Can anyone explain how this can be done ?

Answer (score 1):

Your questions is not specific to OAuth or your authorization server, but applies to all applications that require high availability.

A common solution is to deploy a load balancer in front of your authorization servers. It would accept all incoming requests, and send it any of the available servers, using e.g. a round-robin load balancing algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for some product like Keycloak server which can give you high availability. The tokens created are stored in a central database and if one Auth server is down, another Auth server can serve clients. This can also give you SSO capability.